# Firebase Authentication causes cloud functions to return empty

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function that's supposed to return Items that are sold by a seller. I want to get the seller's profile picture via firebase authentication. But whenever I AWAIT the function

edit: worth noting that mAuth is firebase authentication*

```ts
await mAuth.geUser(sellerData.UID);
```

the application returns me an empty json or []

Here is the full code for the function, the error occurs on line 11 or somewhere around there.

```
export const getHottestItems = functions.region("asia-east2").https.onRequest(async (data, response) => {
    try {
        var arrayItem = new Array<Item>();
        let itemSeller: Seller;
        const sellerSnapshot = await db.collection("users").get();
        // this is the list of promises/awaitables for all items
        const promises = new Array<Promise<FirebaseFirestore.QuerySnapshot<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>>>();
        sellerSnapshot.forEach(async (sellerDoc) => {
            const sellerData = sellerDoc.data();
            // THIS PART CAUSES THE API TO RETURN []
            const sellerAuth = await mAuth.getUser(sellerData.UID);
            // check for non null / empty strings
            if (sellerData.Name as string && sellerData.UID as string) {
                // this is all the seller information we need
                itemSeller = new Seller(sellerData.Name, sellerData.UID, sellerAuth.photoURL); // placeholder profile picture
                const refItem = sellerDoc.ref.collection("Items");
                // push all the promises to a list so we can run all our queries in parallel
                promises.push(refItem.get());
            }
        });
        // wait for all promises to finish and get a list of snapshots
        const itemSnapshots = await Promise.all(promises);
        itemSnapshots.forEach((ItemSnapshot) => {
            ItemSnapshot.forEach((ItemDoc) => {
                // get the data
                const itemData = ItemDoc.data();
                // if title is not null, the rest of the fields are unlikely to be.
                if (itemData.Title as string) {
                    // the rest of the logic to convert from database to model is in the constructor
                    arrayItem.push(new Item(ItemDoc.id, itemData.Title, itemSeller, itemData.Likes, itemData.ListedTime, itemData.Rating, itemData.Description, itemData.TransactionInformation, itemData.ProcurementInformation, itemData.Category, itemData.Stock, itemData.Image1, itemData.Image2, itemData.Image3, itemData.Image4, itemData.AdvertisementPoints, itemData.isDiscounted, itemData.isRestocked));
                }
            });
        });
        // sort by performance level
        arrayItem = arrayItem.sort(x => x.Performance);
        if (data.body.userID) {
            arrayItem = await markLikedItems(data.body.userID, arrayItem);
        }
        //send the responseafter all the final modifications
        response.send(arrayItem);
    } catch (err) {
        // log the error
        console.log(err);
        response.status(500).send(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: What it exactly `mAuth`? Also, have a look at https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404 & https://www.coreycleary.me/why-does-async-await-in-a-foreach-not-actually-await/

Comment: mAuth is firebase authentication

Comment: Instead of saying "mAuth is firebase authentication", it would be better to show the complete, minimal code that reproduces the problem, so we don't have to guess what other code is running here.  The question should also show the data in the database you're working with, and explain the desired result.